# How to Make Custom Colored Scoreboards

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am on the `mchost.co` server and I want to know how to make colored scoreboards on it for my Minehut server. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Colored it terms of colored names for players or color on the sidebar

Answer (score -1):

Are you running on bukkit / spigot? If so, you can use a scoreboard plugin, for example [Featherboard](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/featherboard.2691/) (paid, $15) or if you are looking for free one [QuickBoard](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/quickboard-free-scoreboard-plugin-scroller-changeable-text-placeholderapi-anti-flicker.15057/). They both support colors.